# How to remove all breakpoints in one step in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How to remove all breakpoints in one step in Google Chrome? Using version 11.

[update]

There is now a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72199) for this.

[update]

The [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72199) is closed (Dec 2011)!

Comment: Is there no `Deactivate all breakpoints` button, like in Chrome 9?

Comment: @Krik: Version 11 is a beta one. They have a nightly build. @Matt: When I refresh the page, which is very often, breakpoints reactivate.

Comment: I am looking at Chrome Version 51, you need to go to Source > Debug pane (where watch, call stack, break points...). Right click the breakpoints pane (you need to have some breakpoints to see the option), and you ll find, "Remove All Breakpoints".

Comment: PLEASE community HELP TO VOTE at http://bugs.chromium.org A SIMPLE SOLUTION to this problem... Even nowadays (2019) **NO SIMPLE SOLUTION**.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

This is now possible in **Sources** tab of Chrome Developer Tools.
Please see screen grab below and right click within the "Breakpoints" section of the left window.

[image]

Comment: Works for Chrome version 70 as well

Answer (score 126):

Since recently (Chrome 18), you can **right-click any breakpoint in the Breakpoints pane** and voila! The "Remove All JavaScript Breakpoints" popup menu item!

[image]

Comment: There has been so much happening with Chrome lately, that it becomes difficult to see what is happening where, Apparently I am on Chrome 27 and I am unable to disable all Breakpoints using above approach. These options are missing for me. It hangs my whole browser and I need to go back to Firefox/firebug. Ideas?

Comment: Perhaps I'm just thick, but I think the screenshot here is a little deceptive - right-click menus usually appear to the bottom-right of the cursor, so it looks like you're right-clicking on the source code, but in fact you have to right-click on the Breakpoints pane (as the text of your answer admittedly states, but it's only clear what that means if you notice the Breakpoints pane at all in the image or already know it exists). I think the screenshot from thirumalaa srinivas's answer below is better; perhaps you should pinch it and use it instead of yours?

Comment: @Mike Perhaps you're right-clicking in the wrong place - while this answer is correct, the screenshot is a little deceptive and has already mislead me and at least one other commenter on this question. See my comment above. This works for me in Chrome 31, and according to the answer it worked in Chrome 18, so I'd be surprised if it didn't work in Chrome 27.

Comment: Even worse when you've got `Split panels vertically when docked to right` and you're docking right, the `Breakpoints` pane is *below* the Sources pane, and not as close to the context above. Like reading "He went to the\nthe store" with one "the", I just figured he meant the line number pane with breakpoints was the "breakpoints pane". Guess JS coder == reading comprehension fail.  ;^)  Thanks, commenters. Useful to edit the picture?

Comment: The "Breakpoints" subsection title should have a "+" (like for "XHR Breakpoints") and that will expand options like "clear all breakpoints"

Comment: is there any shortcut for it?  it would be convenient to have f9 for it

Comment: This answer is now outdated, they no longer have these options in the right click context menu with Version 55.0.2883.87 m

Answer (score 21):

Chrome Devtools crashed everytime I tried to access the `Sources` panel because of a breakpoint on a minified Javascript file.

To remove all breakpoints without access to the interface, you can do the following:

1. Open inspector-on-inspector : undock first inspector and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to open the second
2. On the inspector-on-inspector console, execute the following:

   ```
   window.localStorage.breakpoints = [];
   ```
3. Close the inspectors and reload the page. Now the breakpoints are gone.

Comment: I run at console `window.localStorage.breakpoints = [];`  and nothing...

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the question literally. How did you discover this method?

Answer (score 13):

Under Sources, you can click button marked with red on picture below or use shortcut Ctrl + F8 just like tool tip is showing (activate / deactivate breakpoints). A little bit lower under 'Breakpoints' you will see all your breakpoints. If you choose to disable all, they will be grayed out.

[image]

Comment: but not remove only deactivate

Comment: This seems to be the only workaround at the moment?  Looks like they removed it from the right-click menus.

Comment: What would be a good reason to take down such a needed functionality?

Answer (score 7):

solution [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91666).

> To purge all breakpoints open inspector on inspector (undock first
>   inspector and hit ctrl-shift-I to open the second) and run
>   "WebInspector.settings.domBreakpoints.set([])" in second inspector's
>   console.

Comment: This does not work for me.  I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: WebInspector is not defined`

Answer (score 3):

1. new Tabs;  Ctrl+Shift+J to Console;  Access URL
2. Open the Chrome task manager and end the tab page.
3. Ctrl+Shift+J  to  Application  ->  Service Workers (Offiline)   -> Refresh
4. to Sources  Cancel Breakpoint

Success

Comment: Can you update this one? Looks like you have to open the Chrome menu (not Dev Tools menu), select "More Tools" then "Task Manager", or Shift + Esc. 

I had to stop the processes a few times, reload the page, and remove all breakpoints. But eventually it took and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to de-activate all break points using:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>

Comment: This just disables them :(

Answer (score 1):

In my case Uninstall and new installation of Chrome was without any success.

Also window.localStorage.clear() did not help.

My "last chance solution" is to remove entire directory where Chrome is storing its data.
First turn off your Chrome.
Then look at this path "c:\Users\ {your_user} \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\". Here try to delete all what is in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear all inspector settings and reload the inspector. It helped me with fantom breakpoint I could not remove in any other way. Open inspector and go to Preferences -> Sync -> Restore defaults and reload (at the bottom).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Developer tools and expand Breakpoint section.
2. Right click on expanded area of breakpint and there will be many options lik.