# Remove all breakpoints from chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, breakpoints, google-chrome-devtools

I had enabled some break points in Chrome's developer tools for Javascript and now I can not delete them.
Any time I switch to the Developer view I always hit a breakpoint which is really annoying.
Strangely enough in some cases I did not put any break point where it stops. It is a different code alltogether.
How can I remove all the breakpoints?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903302/how-to-remove-all-breakpoints-in-one-step-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It sounds like you've told Chrome to break on all exceptions. On the sources tab, at the bottom left, there are a series of buttons:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome's bottom-left tools with break-on-exceptions button circled]

The one I've circled (a filled hexagon with two vertical lines in it) cycles between breaking on all exceptions, on just uncaught exceptions, and not breaking at all. Click it until it's black (not blue or purple).

For other breakpoints, they're on the right-hand side under the category "Breakpoints" (you probably knew that :-) ). Right-click and choose "Remove all breakpoints".

Answer (score 16):

[image][image]

You can activate/deactivate breakpoints  with ctrl-F8 (Chrome version 49)
There is a:

```
        "deactivate  / activate"
```

crossed over black arrow / blue arrow

above the watch pane, 
There is a list of breakpoints below

Watch, 
Call stack, 
Scope
where you can activate/deactivate breakpoints individually

[image]

Right click in this list, and you can remove all breakpoints.

Answer (score 7):

You can **right-click** on any breakpoints in the **Source** tab and click on **Remove breakpoint** or **right-click** on the right side on **Breakpoints section** and **Remove all breakpoints**!

[image: You can see the picture here]

Answer (score 2):

On Google Chrome    78.0.3904.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

1. Either right click on Any XHR or fetch of
2. Or un-check the checkbox
3. It will also show the list of break points you put

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any breakpoints, but it still breaks on a random location, just create a new random breakpoint anywhere and then you'll have access to remove all breakpoints.