# How to remove breakpoints in chrome debugger

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs

When I add breakpoints to source code in the Chrome Debugger, it works as expected.

However if I then remove the breakpoint and refresh the page, the breakpoints return. Likewise, if I close and reopen developer tools, the breakpoints return.

The only way that chrome forgets the breakpoint is if I close the tab altogether and open a new tab and reload the url, but as this requires a lengthy authentication process it is not ideal.

This is a react app, and I am using React Developer Tools Chrome Plugin - the breakpoints are placed in the source files not the transpiled code.

I am transpiling using babel via webpack, if it is at all pertinant to the issue.

Does anyone know if there is a solution to this issue - I can Deactivate all My Breakpoints, but they still return on a refesh (and are reactivated).
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903302/how-to-remove-all-breakpoints-in-one-step-in-google-chrome

Comment: Removing all break points by right clicking does seem to have helped. The problem hasn't gone away entirely but it seems more infrequent. It seems there is some sort of caching bug in the debugger, causing the break points to come back - especially when they are added and removed by clicking on the line number in the source.
It seems that the Breakpoints accordion works better in this respect.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? It's been plaguing me for months now.

Comment: No Josh, this is still an issue for me, I have just got into the habit of removing all breakpoints when I re-open the dev tools, because they have often un-helpfully re-appeared.